# Selenium-wire - Module Not Found

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, seleniumwire

Hi i would like run the next script but selenium-wire doesn't work, someone can help me?

**Code:**

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import time

options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': 'http://user:pass@ip:port',
        'https': 'https://user:pass@ip:port',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    }
}
path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path', seleniumwire_options=options)

driver.get('http://whatismyipaddress.com')

time.sleep(8)

driver.quit()
```

**Error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gomez\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2021.2\scratches\scratch.py", line 1, in <module>
    from seleniumwire import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seleniumwire'
```

**pip list**:

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7D7k.png)